# How to access object value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have this array of an object, I need to select the 'default_image' or 'label' or 'html' values using loop. But unable to do this.

```
var panel_array = [{
    "Panel":{
        "Panel_1":{
            "default_image":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/jigyaasa_content_static/interactive_item/panel_1.png",
            "label":"Panel List 1",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list1'></dl>"
        },
        "Panel_2":{
            "default_image":"<img src='"+themeUrl+"/prepengine/images/Interactive-items/panel2.png'",
            "label":"Panel List 2",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list2'></dl>"
        }
    },
    "List":{
        "l1":{
            "default_image":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/jigyaasa_content_static/interactive_item/panel_1.png",
            "label":"Panel List 1",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list1'></dl>"
        },
        "l2":{
            "default_image":"<img src='"+themeUrl+"/prepengine/images/Interactive-items/panel2.png'",
            "label":"Panel List 2",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list2'></dl>"
        }
    },
}]
```

I tried this and it prints all the values but how to access single value like if i want only 'label' or i want only 'html':

```
panel_array.map(data => {
                for (var items in data) {
                    for(var dt in data[items]){
                        var ab = data[items];
                        for(var xx in ab) { 
                            var ii = ab[xx];
                            for(var oo in ii){ 
                                console.log(ii[oo]); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: It seems your code is iterating 4 levels deep but your array is only 3 levels deep?

Comment: On third level i tried console(xx.label) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) of array, [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
const panel_array = [{
  "Panel": {
    "Panel_1": {
      "default_image": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/jigyaasa_content_static/interactive_item/panel_1.png",
      "label": "Panel List 1",
      "html": "<dl class='drop_list1'></dl>"
    },
    "Panel_2": {
      "default_image": "<img src='/prepengine/images/Interactive-items/panel2.png'",
      "label": "Panel List 2",
      "html": "<dl class='drop_list2'></dl>"
    }
  },
  "List": {
    "l1": {
      "default_image": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/jigyaasa_content_static/interactive_item/panel_1.png",
      "label": "Panel List 1",
      "html": "<dl class='drop_list1'></dl>"
    },
    "l2": {
      "default_image": "<img src='/prepengine/images/Interactive-items/panel2.png'",
      "label": "Panel List 2",
      "html": "<dl class='drop_list2'></dl>"
    }
  },
}];


panel_array.forEach(o => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(key => {
    Object.values(o[key]).forEach(item => {
      //you can access whatever you need
      console.log(item);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add an `if clause`:

```js
var panel_array = [{
    "Panel":{
        "Panel_1":{
            "default_image":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/jigyaasa_content_static/interactive_item/panel_1.png",
            "label":"Panel List 1",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list1'></dl>"
        },
        "Panel_2":{
            "default_image":"<img src='/prepengine/images/Interactive-items/panel2.png'",
            "label":"Panel List 2",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list2'></dl>"
        }
    },
    "List":{
        "l1":{
            "default_image":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/jigyaasa_content_static/interactive_item/panel_1.png",
            "label":"Panel List 1",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list1'></dl>"
        },
        "l2":{
            "default_image":"<img src='/prepengine/images/Interactive-items/panel2.png'",
            "label":"Panel List 2",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list2'></dl>"
        }
    },
}]
panel_array.map(data => {
   for (var items in data) {
     for(var dt in data[items]){
       var ab = data[items];
       for(var xx in ab) { 
           var ii = ab[xx];
           for(var oo in ii){ 
             if (oo == "label" || oo == "html") console.log(ii[oo]); 
           }
       }
     }
   }
})
```

Comment: If i want to append the values in my html then how i will apply the condition?`$('.modal_panel').append('<div class="thumbnail btn"><img src="images/panel1.png style="width:100%"><div class="caption"><p>'+ii[oo]+'</p></div></div>');` I want to put my label inside <p> tag and my I=image inside <img> tag

Comment: @wizkhalifa just add your `.append()` method to the place where i wrote the `console.log()`

Comment: I already did this `for(var oo in ii) { 
                                if (oo == "label" || oo == "default_image")  {
                                   $('.modal_panel').append('<div class="thumbnail btn"><img src="images/panel1.png style="width:100%"><div class="caption"><p>'+ii[oo]+'</p></div></div>');
                                }
                            }` Now how to put default image inside image tag and label inside p tag

Comment: @wizkhalifa `$('.modal_panel').append(ii[oo]);`

Comment: I need to append them in my tags only

Answer (score 0):

```js
let themeUrl = 'MockmyUrl';
let panel_array = [{
    "Panel":{
        "Panel_1":{
            "default_image":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/jigyaasa_content_static/interactive_item/panel_1.png",
            "label":"Panel List 1",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list1'></dl>"
        },
        "Panel_2":{
            "default_image":"<img src="+themeUrl+"/prepengine/images/Interactive-items/panel2.png'",
            "label":"Panel List 2",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list2'></dl>"
        }
    },
    "List":{
        "l1":{
            "default_image":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/jigyaasa_content_static/interactive_item/panel_1.png",
            "label":"Panel List 1",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list1'></dl>"
        },
        "l2":{
            "default_image":"<img src='"+themeUrl+"/prepengine/images/Interactive-items/panel2.png'",
            "label":"Panel List 2",
            "html":"<dl class='drop_list2'></dl>"
        }
    },
}];
let images = [];
let lables = [];
let htmls = [];
let output  = panel_array.forEach((ele) => {
  Object.values(ele).forEach((ele2) => {
    Object.values(ele2).forEach((ele3) => {
      let {default_image, label, html} = ele3;
      images.push(default_image);
      lables.push(label);
      htmls.push(html);
    });
  });
});
console.log(images);
console.log('----------------');
console.log(lables);
console.log('----------------');
console.log(htmls);
```